# Tidyverse Install Error--how do I address this dplyr conflict?

Tags: r, dplyr

I receive the following error when I try to download tidyverse - please help!

```
-- Conflicts --
tidyverse_conflicts() --

x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Comment: This is a message. You have downloaded and loaded the tidyverse already. This message is telling you if you call either `filter()` or `lag()` then you will be calling these functions from `dplyr` not `stats`. You can still use these two functions from the stats package but you will have to use `stats::` before, e.g. `stats::filter()`.

Comment: This is not an error. `dplyr` choose to name it's own functions using the same names as the stats function. This is just a message that has happened. This should not cause any problems with code.